# SharePoint 2013 large library migration issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, migration, library, sharepoint-server

My situation is this: I have a MS SharePoint 2013 on-premises server; a specific site there, has a Library with 97.000 items in it (different folders&files); it is used by MS Dynamics.

I have to migrate everything to Sharepoint Online(365). Including this list, and keeping it's structure.

The problem is related to that 97.000 Items list. No solution worked; Metalogix, Sharegate ... nothing.

Anybody have any suggestion? Thanks.

LE:
1. Well at first there was the View problem. Not even Metalogix could see the list, since AllDocuments had 97.000 Items. The I created 20 view, each with a filter, so they display only 5.000 items each. Then from Metalogix I could view this Library using this view. So I try'd migrating in batches. Basically migrate by view. This did not work.
"Open in Explorer View" also does not work, shows "folder is empty".
2. I have contacted the people from SLIM Applications, regarding their Migration Manager tool. Unfortunately it did not work for me, but they try'd to be as helpful as possible; the item count limitation could not be surpassed.
3. I have opened a ticket to MS Support, waiting for an update.
As an FYI: this situation was created by another on their tools, MS Dynmics, which stores client information in this SP Library.

Comment: How did the solutions _not_ work? Did you try migrating in smaller batches, maybe just one folder at a time?

Comment: Well at first there was the View problem. Not even Metalogix could see the list, since AllDocuments had 97.000 Items. The I created 20 view, each with a filter, so they display only 5.000 items each. Then from Metalogix I could view this Library using this view. So I try'd migrating in batches. Basicaly migrate by view. This did not work.

Comment: You should be able to set the list view threshold on the source system to 100k, after which SP doesn't prevent viewing these lists. It's done per web application in Central Admin.

Comment: @Jussi Palo : I know what you mean, but from my knowledge that would put alot of presure on the DB Server; and I'm not sure if a tool like Metalogix would work anyway.

Comment: Increasing the threshold doesn't _in itself_ put any more pressure on the DB. Only when you query large lists. I'd recommend increasing the threshold, and seeing if you can view the files in Explorer View or with migration tools. If yes, then you can decide with too to use. You can do it during times when there is less users in the system and even monitor server performance, but I doubt you will notice any big peaks - 97k is not that much.

Answer (score 1):

So finally I have a solution; it's a combo of a few things:
 - did an export from the OnPrem Sharepoint, from the GUI
 - packed everything with Powershell using "New-SPOMigrationPackage" and moved the package to a Fileshare
 - used ShareGate to migrate this package to SPO, using a specific Sharepoint Template "Data Center"
The test migration ran smoothly. Everything should be ready in a few days, also on Prod.

FYI: Sharegate license costs 3995 USD / Year; and you also get the Sharegate Desktop, which is basically an Admin GUI for SPO. So, useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that "Open in Explorer View" does not work. Can you browse 
to a subfolder in the SP2016 system (using Internet Explorer) and then 
open explorer view? 
If that works you can use the tool Slim Companion migration manager to 
drag folders from the explorer window into SP Online. We have used it 
for large file share migrations (100+ Gb) to SP Online.

Comment: "Explorer View" does not work because of the Item Count. As I know it has a 2k item list limit. Even if I create a view cu less then 2k items in it, it will not work, since, apparently, it's reading the library item count, not the view.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, I would strongly recommend you to migrate contents from On-Prem to Cloud using PowerShell cmdlets **"*-SPOMigrationPackage"**.

If you have a subscription to Azure, you will have everything you might need to get your files from On-Prem to Cloud.

It is pretty straight forward, all you need to do is to create **migration packages** and define the destination to SharePoint Online, and put them into scheduled jobs for the delivery.

There is a good step-by-step tutorial here:

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2015/09/22/step-by-step-migrate-files-to-sharepoint-online-office-365-import-service/

Comment: Thank you for your response; I just got back to the office and will look into that today. Be back later with details. Have a great new year!

Comment: let us know if it worked or not, i'm kinda curious to find out the result of your migration given the challenges and environment you have described, it looks very interesting!

Comment: Yes for sure, as soon as I have a working solution, I will post it here. At this moment we are try'n a few Powershell scripts.

Comment: May I point you to another PowerShell script that deliver migration? Try this one: https://github.com/MrDrSushi/SPOPSM